# How to signal a loop to continue the execution instead of using sleep

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to create a thread that will sit and wait to detect new objects in a `vector` (the queue). Using a loop will crush the resources on the given machine, so I am trying to figure out how I can create a blocking thread that waits for a notification from the main thread.

The application will essentially wait for new objects in the `vector` and do some heavy IO operations - reading large files, compressing them, and writing back to disk.

Comment: What kind of application are you coding? What are your IO operations? On which operating system? C++11 or some older standard? Please **edit your question** to improve it and give a lot more context & motivation

Comment: BTW, the "signal" word in your question is *very* ambiguous. Do not confuse [Unix signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal) with [signaling or broardcasting a condition variable](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConVarSignal)

Comment: What OS/platform will you be using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sup>(I am not sure to understand what you want; I'm trying to guess; asynchronous IO could mean [aio(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/aio.7.html) but then you won't speak of threads to do them; however I am supposing you are on Linux - adapt my answer to other OSes)</sup>

You might consider using [condition variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)#Condition_variables) using [std::condition_variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) with [std::mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) (probably some other thread would signal the condition variable, e.g. when adding to the queue). If you are not familiar with the concepts, see [this pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) (then adapt the ideas to C++11 [threads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread)).

On POSIX systems such as Linux, you can check that a set of file descriptors is readable or writable using [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), etc... in some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop); see also [this](http://davmac.org/davpage/linux/async-io.html); and you can *carefully* use `SIGIO` (see [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) first ...; beware that you can only call *async-signal-safe functions* from signal handlers - which excludes most of C++ or C standard libraries; in practice, you can safely set some `volatile sigatomic_t` flags inside it, and test these flags elsewhere, e.g. in the event loop). And you could also setup some [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) to self at program initialization time, and [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) to it from a signal handler (BTW, this trick is recommended by Qt, in [Calling Qt Functions From Unix Signal Handlers](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/unix-signals.html)), or within a mutexed critical section.

PS. Do not confuse [Unix signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal) with [signaling or broadcasting a condition variable](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConVarSignal) (which you cannot reliably do from inside a Unix [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) handler).